# Jquery post doesnt get correct path

Tags: jquery, directory-structure

question is simple but I am really pissed off. I am using jquery post to check if user mail exist.

var e;

```
$.post("../backend-stuff/check_email.php", {email_check:email.toString(), function(result){
   e = result;
});
```

My Main Directory is : Project Folder

I have:
Project/backend-stuff/
Project/js-stuff/

folders.

The point is that jquery always takes localhost as main directory.

I mean, it gets "../backend-stuff/check_email.php" as "localhost/backend-stuff/check_email.php" and it says failed to load file in javascript.

I dont get it, I use this double stop thing elsewhere and it works.

"../backend-stuff/" equals "Project/backend-stuff/" as far as I know.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: my jscirpt file that i use this code is inside, "js-stuff" folder. so I need to be outside to get to backend-stuff folder. But i cant do it. The problem is this works elsewhere for example in CSS  but not in this js file.

Comment: try to add more `../` or remove ... until it works

Comment: What does "../" exactly mean? The folder outside of the current folder? Or something else?

Comment: `../` means move up one directory, which is not what you want. Sounds like you want `"backend-stuff/checkmail.php"` Can also use full path from `localhost` by putting `/` at beginning...everything after will be relative to domain (localhost)

Comment: Thank you, but I am really disappointed by jQuery now, cause even though I use complete path, Firebug says: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/Project/backend-stuff/check_email_exist.php"

Answer (score 0):

$.post is using http protocol by default, which means that it's automatically resolving the domain name of the server the file is running on.
In your case it's your own machine, which means "localhost".

What you need to do is to setup a web server on your machine that will make it possible for your file to be located properly. You should take a look at wamp (windows), xamp (osx) or lamp (linux).

Then put your Projects folder inside the www directory.

If you really want to load the file use this url: 'file://../Projects/...' but your PHP file won't be interpreted as PHP and it's not going to be executed properly.

Comment: Ok, the point is that, I have xampp, and this is where my javascript code that runs post function:
Project/js-stuff/login.js

What I want is to access another file from the above javascirpt file. The file I want to access is on this path:
Project/backend-stuff/check_email.php

Comment: Ok I see, what you mean, but then why the files in htdocs are not usable like this?